# Upload file to Node.js server using Socket.io-stream from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, node.js, socket.io

I'm writing a native iOS client to interact with a Node.js server using the [Socket.IO-objc wrapper](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc). I'm currently able to send individual events to the server just fine. However, the server is using [Socket.IO-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) to handle upload file streams, and I need to make my iOS code interact with it somehow. My socket.io wrapper doesn't seem to have any relevant API for accomplishing this. The receiving server.js code is like:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connection occurring");
    ss(socket).on('uploadFile', function (stream, data, callback) {
      //...I can't get a 'stream' to this event for it to work with
    });
    socket.on('passwordLogin', function (data, callback) {
      //...I can cause these kind of events just fine
    });
    //...other event declarations
 }
```

I typically call events in this manner, and it works fine for 'socket.on' declared events:

```
[_socket sendEvent:@"passwordLogin" 
          withData:@{...login info...} 
    andAcknowledge:aCallbackBlock];
```

I figure I need to expand Socket.IO-objc, unless there is something I'm missing, with something like:

```
//TODO: Attempt to expand SocketIO to include streams.
- (void) sendEvent:(NSString *)eventName withStream:(NSStream*) stream withData:(id) data   andAcknowledge:(SocketIOCallback) function
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:eventName forKey:@"name"];

    // do not require arguments
    if (data != nil) {
        [dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:data] forKey:@"args"];
    }

    SocketIOPacket *packet = [[SocketIOPacket alloc] initWithType:@"event"];
    packet.data = [SocketIOJSONSerialization JSONStringFromObject:dict error:nil];
    packet.pId = [self addAcknowledge:function];
    //Is this even a valid approach?
    packet.stream = stream;//<--NEW BIT
    if (function) {
       packet.ack = @"data";
    }
    [self send:packet];
}
```

I'm pretty lost as to what exactly to do, having never really worked with server communications before. I've followed Apple documentation about the built-in NSStream and CFStream objects, but it doesn't seem to get me any closer to interacting with the server's event. Any help is appreciated, as I'm a bit at my wit's end.

Comment: Have you found any solution for your issue ?!

Comment: @Sewerbird Have you found any solution?